# How do I include a body into a tagfile

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2, tagfile

I have a tagfile I intend to use as an input template:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <div class="qr">
        <label>#{question}</label>
        <div class="helpButton"></div>
        <!-- body here -->
        <!-- errors output eventually to go here -->
    </div>

</ui:composition>
```

It is stored in my `/WEB-INF/tags` folder with a `.taglib.xml` and necessary `web.xml` context-param.

I understand it could be used as follows:

```
<g:question question="What is your name?" id="firstname">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.firstname}" />
</g:question>
```

at the moment this is in its most basic form. I intend to use various and complex inputs. but the layout of the label etc will always need to stay the same.

How do I include the body of the `<g:question>` in the tagfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<ui:insert>`.

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <div class="qr">
        <label>#{question}</label>
        <div class="helpButton"></div>
        <ui:insert />
        <!-- errors output eventually to go here -->
    </div>

</ui:composition>
```

Do note that you can even use `<ui:define name="...">` and `<ui:insert name="...">` on tagfiles like as you usually do on templates.

Comment: Thanks again Bauke. JSF would be a lot more difficult without your SO contributions.