# Is it possible to pass on the children of a composite component CC as the cell contents of CC's panelGrid parent?

Tags: jsf

For example, I have a composite component like this:

```
...
<cc:implementation>
       <h:outputText value="#{binding.label}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{binding.value}" />
       <cc:insertChildren/>
       <h:outputText value="#{cc.some.stuff}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

and I want to use this component inside a four-columns `panelGrid` as follows, such that every child or actual component *inside* my composite component gets placed in its own separate cell of the `panelGrid` (so every instance of my CC would be a row):

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <custom:myComponent blah="bla">
        <foo:whatEverIwantHere />
    </custom:myComponent>
</h:panelGrid>
```

But the problem is the *entire* `custom:myComponent` gets rendered as a single cell of the `panelGrid`, inside a single `td` that is.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822000

Comment: @BalusC does the Facelet tag approch you propose also work with <cc:insertChildren/>? which is explicitly from the composite component namespace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28214221

Comment: @BalusC But actually inside the CC I want to use stuff bound to #{cc} like #{cc.foo}, so is it even possible in JSF?

Comment: Yes, it's possible in tag files too. See duplicate link.